# How to get an ad to play only every 4th time with Unity ads

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

So in my Unity app, I have introduced Unity Ads and I want it to only play say every 4th time they hit replay.

***EDIT: First I started updating the value to the log each time and noticed that it was restarting back to 0 each life, so I added static to the int `gamesPlayed`, and now it works as expected.***

I created an int and gave it a value of 0. Each time the user hits reply the int gamesPlayed should increase by 1. Then if it's divisible by 4, it should play the app, but it doesn't work at all.

If I swap it around, it works too often, `4 % gamesPlayed == 0`, so the code works that way, why not the other way?

EDIT: I used `gamesPlayed` int as I figure later on I might do something with displaying how many games the player has played, so I wanted to keep track of that too.

```js
int gamesPlayed = 0;

case "Replay":
  isRestartPressed = true;
  restart();
  playerController.currentState = playerController.playerStates.idle;
  gamesPlayed++;
  if(gamesPlayed % 4 == 0) {
    if (Advertisement.isReady ()) { Advertisement.Show ();}
  }
  
  break;
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the error must be somewhere else, because this code should work [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/1kv46z30/) - could you give a little more context code?

Comment: I editited to include the full button :/ when i swap the gamesPlayed and 4 around it works fine though just works too often...

is there an easier way to do this? i was thinking of doing a random between 1 and 10 and if its 9 or 10 then play ad but thats too random..

Comment: Maybe `Advertisement.isReady()` is falsy?

Comment: can confirm that advertisement.ready is returning true

Comment: Got it working thanks, Just had to make gamesPlayed a static int